# How to get hardware information without parsing /proc/*info files in C program

Tags: c, linux, hardware

How to get the hardware information using `C` code in Linux like information regarding `CPU`, `RAM`, `Network adaptor`, `Video adaptor`, `Sound adaptor` etc.?

I don't want to parse `/proc/*info` file and also don't want to use `hwinfo/dmidecode`. Is there any open source library available?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the methods you know about already, like `/proc`?  Have you seen the programs `dmidecode` and `lspci`?

Comment: Those are all different questions. For physical memory, for instance, you can do `return (size_t)sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES) * (size_t)sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE );`

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `/proc`? It's the standard interface (and, in many cases, the *only* interface) to a lot of the information the kernel publishes to userspace.

Comment: and one more thing i just wanted to know..is dmidecode/hwinfo/lspci available on all distributions???

Comment: Perhaps  sysfs (/sys) ?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: 
 
somewhere mentioned.. if we parse /proc/*info then.. Be aware, however, that the names, semantics, and output formats of entries in the /proc file system might change in new Linux kernel revisions. If you use them in a program, you should make sure that the program's behavior degrades gracefully if the /proc entry is missing or is formatted unexpectedly.

Comment: @duskwuff: 
 
somewhere mentioned.. if we parse /proc/*info then.. Be aware, however, that the names, semantics, and output formats of entries in the /proc file system might change in new Linux kernel revisions. If you use them in a program, you should make sure that the program's behavior degrades gracefully if the /proc entry is missing or is formatted unexpectedly.

Comment: So you're trying to avoid `/proc` simply out of fear that its format may change?  I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: @RaviBhushan Who mentioned that? They're wrong. The files in `/proc` are considered a stable kernel ABI. They won't be changed unexpectedly.

Comment: The hardware information is migrating (well, almost complete) to sysfs, so you have to look at it in /sys directory, where it's normally mounted.  This is the approach the system utilities follow.  You have also most of the configuration options through this filesystem.